# What’s the difference between the JavaScript module pattern and its alternatives?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope, javascript-namespaces

What's, practically speaking, the difference between the following 2 patterns?

#### A

```
mySpace = mySpace || {}
mySpace.isObsolete = function() {};
mySpace.hipsterYear = 2006;
```

usage:

```
var iable = mySpace.isObsolete();
var year = mySpace.hipsterYear;
```

#### B (i.e. the module pattern)

```
mySpace = (function(){
  var obj = {};
  var someVar = 2012;
  obj.hipsterYear = 2006;
  obj.isObsolete: function() {};
  return obj;
}());
```

usage:

```
var iable = mySpace.isObsolete();
var year = mySpace.hipsterYear;
```

In B, the anonymous function creates a scope in which someVar is not accessible from the outside. I guess such a construct is not possible in A?
So, A and B differ in terms of created scope.

What are the differences regarding namespacing? Are A and B equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

B is commonly called the 'module pattern' and allows the option to use the object oriented approach of having public and private access to variables and methods, whereas with A everything is public. Douglas Crockford explains it best [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html).

This is generally a good idea, as using the approach in A allows everything to be vulnerable to interference from other code/coders. This increases the likelihood of obscure bugs emerging if someone (possibly you) decides to take shortcuts.